# Save Slow motion video with ffmpeg on android devices

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate, slowmotion

I want to save videos in slow motion through my android app.I tried to convert videos into slow motion by changing frame rate.

I used the following commands,first command is dumping 30 frames per second from videos to a temp directory, and then second command is using these images to  create a video with reduced or faster frame rate and then i am deleting all the images from temp directory.

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -r 30/1 img%03d.png

ffmpeg -framerate 15/1 -i img%03d.png -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out4.mp4
```

But this is a very slow operation. It is taking like forever even for small videos.

I even tried to change PTS(presentation time stamp) of videos, but it is not working properly on android phones
using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" output.mkv
```

as suggested here: 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Can anybody suggest me how can i make it fast. Is it necessary to save frames to a temp directory, can i pass the output of ffmpeg process to another ffmpeg process executing concurrently through some method.

Is there any other ffmpeg command to save the videos in slow motion?

Comment: Your first method is not encouraged. See [here](http://blog.grio.com/2012/01/fast-and-slow-motion-video-with-ffmpeg.html) for more details. Also include the full console output for the second method which adjust `setpts` and which is important for us to guide you. What do you exactly mean by "not working properly"?

Comment: By not working properly i mean audio is not in sync in processed video,it is not getting slowed down,
If i remove audio by using filter -an , video is getting slow properly

Comment: Your approach will not slow down the audio tempo as expected. It is just for video. Use  [atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#atempo) to adjust the audio speed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use below command to create slow motion video using ffmpeg-

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-filter_complex", "[0:v]setpts=2.0*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]", "-b:v", "2097k", "-r", "60", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", outputFileAbsolutePath};
```

Check out [this](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/) post on my blog for complete tutorial